# QTabWidget: determine pages to be QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtabwidget

MainWindow of my Qt application has QTabWidget, where each tab is a QTableWidget. I need to get access to the selected cell of a current table (with `currentRow()` and `currentColumn()`). But when I'm taking pointer to the table with `ui->tabWidget->currentWidget()` result is QWidget* so for it methods like `currentRow()` don't exist.

Is there any way to determine that all pages of QTabWidget are members of QTableWidget class?

Comment: Why don't you use [`QObject::findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren) to retrieve `QTableWidget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html) to check if an object of type `QObject` is an object of type `T` inherits from `QObject`

```
QWidget *widget = ui->tabWidget->currentWidget();
QTableWidget *tableWidget = qobject_cast<QTableWidget*>(widget);
if (tableWidget != 0)
{
    /// Do work
}
```

By the way, you can get all `QTableWidget` in you tab by

```
QList<QTableWidget *> allTables = ui->tabWidget->findChildren<QTableWidget *>();
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'm new with Qt and didn't see `findChildren()` in documetation of QTabWidget, so became quite confused :)

Comment: @Tami `qobject_cast` actually could be thought as `instanceof` operator in Java language. It's very handy in Qt!

Comment: @Tami `findChildren` is a method of `QObject`

Comment: @Danh I understand, only meant that I didn't see it in the list of methods, which could be used by `QTabWidget`